# Generating a C# .net 7 class diagram from multiple files showing all relations within the project

Tags: c#, .net-core, class-diagram

Is there a way to generate a C# using .net 7 showing all relations within the project. Stuff like inheriting classes, members of other classes, and references to other classes methods etc. It does not have to show non custom classes like SFML.Audio or SYSTEM.Random.

I have tried using visual studio class designer. but perhaps due to not supporting .net core it does not show relations outside inheritance by default, and seem to only be able to show relations from members to other classes, not to / in methods.

I have tried using a PlantUml generator (https://github.com/pierre3/PlantUmlClassDiagramGenerator) and this does not show references to / in methods.

I have tried using a program called NClass but that could only generate from assemblies, which i couldn't get to work. Perhaps due to me using assemblies like SFML and such.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: @RedStar i am using VS, but to make the PlantUml i used VSCode.